# how to nestle enum within a class?

Tags: c#, enums

I'm trying to figure out how to nestle **enums** within a class. How  would the following code work?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Console2
{
    class Program 
    {
        class a
        {
            enum Days { Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday };
            enum Months : byte { Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec };   
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {          
            Type weekdays = typeof(a.Days);                   

            string s = Enum.GetName(typeof(a.Days), 4);
            Console.WriteLine(s);

            Console.WriteLine("The values of the Days Enum are:");
            foreach (int i in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Days)))
            Console.WriteLine(i);

            Console.WriteLine("The names of the Days Enum are:");
            foreach (string str in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Days)))
            Console.WriteLine(str);  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, what happens when you try to compile and run it?

Comment: `string s = Enum.GetName(typeof(a.Days), 4);` is correct, `foreach (int i in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Days)))` is not. From outside of the `a` class, you have to refer to `a.Days`. Also, I think you need to make it `public enum Days { ...`, or it will be private by default.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by simply declaring the enums as public, as they are private by default.

> ```
>     class a
>     {
>         public enum Days { Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday };
>         public enum Months : byte { Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec };
>     }
> ```